# Magento 2.4.3 Installation Error

Tags: magento2, installation, composer, php-7

I am try to install Magento 2.4.3 with the command in Ubuntu.

After follow all the steps, when I try to run the Magento from browser, it show me error like this :

> Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies
> require a PHP version ">= 7.4.0".

If I check my `php` version, that is already `7.4.23`

I also try

> 1. composer update
> 2. composer self-update

But still facing the same issue.

If anyone have solution then let me know.

Comment: which platform are you using? nginx, ubuntu, apache?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu already written into the question.

Comment: Did you checked with this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65143327/12110977

Answer (score 2):

There might be multiple PHP versions installed on the server.
So you can run the below command to check that.
which PHP;
or
whereis PHP;

Through this, you can get which PHP version is getting called.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple installed PHP versions on your host, please, check which version is used by the composer with the next command - `composer -vvv about`

Comment: This is already show the PHP Version 7.4.23.

Answer (score 0):

**A simple Solution:**

When you use `php -v` on shell, it will tell you which PHP version **cli** is using. But the composer could have use different php version if you have multi php installed.

To run composer with your desired php version, you can use this command

```
/usr/bin/php7.4 /usr/local/bin/composer update
```

or any other composer command with php version.

Note: If php location is different than `/usr/bin/php7.4` then you can get location by using `locate php`

**Other solution if found this:** (But haven't tried it by myself)

Update your `composer.json` file, and add this php version configuration:

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.1.3"
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Try both solutions, but not working.

Comment: can you share the command that you have used with php version?

Comment: for magento I directly use "php bin/magento cache:clean"

Comment: `php bin/magento cache:clean` on this command you are getting error?

Comment: No, the command doesn't have any error. it run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I Check and found the solution that,

When I need to switch the PHP Version from 7.2 to 7.4 I need to run the command like this one.

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Nginx please give me your Nginx config.

Maybe It's happening by your Nginx configuration with php-fpm.

You can verify by yourself with echo phpinfo(); in /pub/index.php to check your PHP version running with Webserver.

Comment: I already write, I use Ubuntu with MySQL and this is into the local environment.

Comment: I mean your PHP CLI is different from PHP running on a web server like apache, or nginx, php-fpm.
We must use phpinfo(); in code to make sure correct PHP version.